# How can i upload as 1cr rows .csv file using django?

Tags: python, django

I am getting a memory error while uploading a CSV file of size around 650 mb with a shape (10882101, 6).
How can i upload such file in postgres using django framework.

Comment: Hi, please try to upload the error that you are seeing.

Comment: We are going to need more information than this. Please provide the entire error output, as well as the the relevant code. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

- You haven't shared much details (error logs, which python package you are using etc).
- You might like to read [Most efficient way to parse a large .csv in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9087039/13499618), https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d
- How I will do it from Django Framework:

  - I will use Celery to run the job as a background process, as waiting for the file to be uploaded completely before returning a response might give a HTTP timeout.
  - [Celery quickstart with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)